# How can I stop archive logs generation on object level (table)

Tags: oracle, oracle12c

We have force logging enabled in our database but I want 2 of my tables not to generate any archive logs as data in these tables can always be regenerated. The size of Archive logs on these tables are very huge (> 302GB) and causing a lot of problems.

So far I have tried to `alter table nologging` and altered the insert queries to use `/*+ append */` hints, but that does not seems to be working for me.

How can I overcome this archive log issue.

Comment: Database logging settings take precedence. Have you had DataGuard configured? If so putting one or more tables in `nologging` mode  will not be a good idea anyway.

Comment: I just want 2 tables not to generate logs, the size of the logs are more than 302GB and that too for a single SP execution.

Comment: You need to provide more information. Why your DB was put into `forelogging` mode in the first place. Data Guard? If so, it needs to stay in the force logging mode otherwise you can introduce an inconsistency between primary and its standby database(s). What exactly are your concerns? the size of redo log files? Redo logs won't grow beyond the size specified upon their creation. Archive logs, on the other hand... are you sure it's redo logs that are 302Gb?

Comment: @Nicholas, its Archive logs I confirmed with the DBA, I have updated the question as well. Thank you for pointing that out.

Comment: Which Oracle database version are you using? You can use `alter table table_name nologging` to minimize generation of redo log hence less amount of redo logs to be archived.

Comment: @JSapkota, version is 12c and I am using this nologging and append hint but for some reason they are not helping

Comment: You have enabled the force logging so that it's logging all the DML no matter whether have enabled or disabled logging for tables

Comment: is there any way I can stop logging for these two tables ? without changing any DB level setting ?